# Is it a good idea to use mongodb , inmemory db and postgres together?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, database-design, in-memory-database, database

Our application deals with both report and transactions (OLAP and OLTP).

The application needs to display the generated report in form of charts and tables. And other part of application deals with data gathering and manipulation(CRUD operations).

As a part of our solution strategy:

1. Will keep the most accessed report data in the inmemory db giving an upper limit to inmmory db size?
2. Postgres for storing all datas required for the application
3. Mongodb for regularly collecting data required for reports from the postgres db.

Comment: [What the hell have you built?](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2hn6skd1kd69wyf/2013-03-11_at_9.34.26_AM_2x.png)

Comment: You have fallen into the trap that some how if some one like facebook uses x techs together then you need to. They are running with over 1 billion users on PHP...I don't think you are anything like them

Comment: This is "Enterprise-y" engineering at work: in other words, likely to be massively over-complex and so "clever" and "optimised" that it barely works at all or performs utterly terribly. Don't solve problems you don't have yet, not at least without some evidence that you might actually have them in future. Start with Pg, let it do its own caching. If you find you need to reduce read loads, scale out to read replicas or add caching (with proper invalidation via `listen`/`notify`) in the app - or, yes, something like Redis. But only when you need it.

Comment: @Sammaye They're also proof that just because you can, doesn't mean you should. PHP. Gah.

Comment: @sergio it would have been rather helpful if you would have suggested the correct approach rather than to make fun of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The simplest design is the best design, unless your requirements dictate something more complex is needed. PostgreSQL alone is mature and proven, and can be tuned to cache data in memory as well. I recommend building directly on PostgreSQL until you find that performance is not sufficient. I use PostgreSQL as our sole database technology for a busy national website and it works great.

At least choose one database to start with instead of three.

Comment: thanks mark fr your solution. Our appliction is collecting large amount of history data to do the forecasting and some other needs for our work. The same data is used for gnerating reports .

As of now, it take quite a long time to show the report in front end. So we thought like, we can make the latest reports availble as inmemory. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Do you know for sure that pulling a report off of disk is your bottleneck? As Mark mentioned PostgreSQL can be tuned to cache data in memory. MongoDB will also cache actively accessed data in memory. You need to make sure you understand what your bottleneck is and adjust for that. This could potentially be scaling hardware as well rather than re-engineering.

Comment: @adihere, to address your comment, look at using date-based partitions with PostgreSQL. That would allow you to work with recent data as a smaller, faster table, but still make much more history available to query as part of the same table if you need it. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html